# How to send a message from a Microsoft Teams bot using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I a building a bot that should engage a 1 on 1 conversation with every user in a company using teams.

I would like to use the post chat message method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However, it is written that it is "Not supported" for Applications.

I am missing something?

PS: I am trying to use Teams as directly as possible without middle stuff like Bot Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely need a bot for this, and to use something called "Proactive Messaging". Please see some similar questions from earlier just this week that will give you some good reading and background, especially:

1. [Proactive Messaging in MS Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561694/proactive-messaging-in-ms-teams/71570856#71570856)
2. [Sending proactive messages from an outside process to organizational users via Teams chat bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547766/sending-proactive-messages-from-an-outside-process-to-organizational-users-via-t/71550069#71550069)

In the 2nd question especially I give links to further reading, samples, and a video with some more background.