# How do you get a notification only teams bot to call the messaging endpoint after initial installation?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a notification only teams bot that is live for a number of customers in production.

Most of the time when it is installed it calls our messaging endpoint and updates the conversation ID so we can send teams notifications to our customers, however sometimes it seems to fail to do this for some reason so our systems don’t get a conversation ID.

We tried incrementing the version number of the teams bot and that didn’t seem to help.

Is there some way to get the conversation ID updated after initial installation?

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-conversation-id
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: I’m not sure that makes sense to me unfortunately. We do mostly get this information on install. But that is only 99% reliable and in the other cases I’m not sure how to begin to manually look up the conversation ID.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: The requirement is that we have a notification only Team bot. Then if we miss the original installation event we don’t seem to be able to trigger the installation callbacks again or get the  conversation ID without access to the Active Directory tenant.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet
Sample-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot
hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547766/sending-proactive-messages-from-an-outside-process-to-organizational-users-via-t - it's around proactive messaging but talks about how to get those ids programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer after contacting Microsoft Support is that it is impossible. The best solution is to have a non-notification only bot and then it works as you'd expect.