# Save ConversationReference on database

Tags: postgresql, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a Teams bot to send proactive messages and I should save the `ConversationReference` on the database but my question is how?

Should I save the whole object or just some proprieties?

I'm using Postgres for the database and I'm build the bot in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need the entire `ConversationReference`. There are a few ways to implement Proactive Messaging, and the most simple requires only a conversation Id and a Service Url. Please see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547766/sending-proactive-messages-from-an-outside-process-to-organizational-users-via-t/71550069#71550069) I posted a few months ago, where I reference some sample code and a video from a talk I gave, which both go into more detail. The samples I link to there are in node and C#, so not Java directly, but you should be able to get a good start between those two.

Comment: Didn't helped as much as I would like since the SDK is really different on Java. Do you think that is a bad idea saving the object itself on the database?

Comment: No that's totally fine as well, go ahead and save that. It's just more than you need is all, but it's fine to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help and btw great talk on building teams apps.

Comment: sure thing and thanks for the kind words